# How do trinitarians manage the contradiction of Heb 11:3?

Tags: hebrews, trinity

> By faith we understand that the universe was created by the word (rhēmati) of God, so that what is seen was not made out of things that are visible.

We know also from John 1 that God made creation through His word or logos.

While the Nicene creed states, referring to the son... Through him all things were made.

Well, which is it? The logos/rhēmati or a son?

Comment: This is a theological question and should be posted on Christianity SX.  One could ask a similar question about Col 1:15-18 (where Jesus creates all things) and 1 Cor 8:6 where Jesus creates all things and God creates all things, and Rev 19:13 where Jesus is the Word of God.

Comment: For trinitarians, Jesus is God (as per John 1:1 and 20:28) and so Heb 11:3 has no contradiction at all.

Comment: ῥήματι θεοῦ just means the author referred to "God said" in Genesis 1, nothing contradictory.

Comment: I'm a Christian and I don't see any contradictions there. Please explain, where is the contradiction?

Comment: Not only is this question off-topic on BH but it is very poor quality. We expect better on Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question needs to explicitly state what the contradiction is, and how it applies specifically to the Trinity doctrine.  As it stands, the only apparent problem is whether it was the Logos or the Son, and effectively all denominations, trinitarian or not, believe that Logos and Son and Jesus and Christ are all references to the same being.